# How to make page scroll when cursor is not in focus

Tags: html, css, reactjs, uiscrollview, tailwind-css

I have a 3-column layout, in which the middle column is scrollable and I don't want other columns to be scrollable. Also the middle Column should be scrollable when cursor is outside the column on anywhere of page basically with the page scroll also but within the screen height ie 100vh. (screen height should never change it should scroll in that keeping other fixed)

I am using tailwindcss and current code is like this

```
 <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 container md:max-w-7xl overflow-hidden">
     <div>
        column 1
     </div>
    <div className="col-span-2 max-h-screen overflow-scroll>
        column 2
     </div>
    <div className="">
        column 3
     </div>
</div
```

This is making the middle section scroll while keeping other fixed but as soon i move cursor away from column the page is not scrolling.

I want to make it scrollable irrespective of my mouse position. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the other columns fixed and make the `div` scrollable.

```
 <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 container md:max-w-7xloverflow-scroll">
     <div className="fixed">
        column 1
     </div>
    <div className="col-span-2 max-h-screen">
        column 2
     </div>
    <div className="fixed">
        column 3
     </div>
</div>
```